# Is it legal to override target in Makefile by order in a file?

Tags: makefile, overriding, warnings

I have a Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
all: target1

target1:
    $(info "target1")

target1:
    $(info "target1 override")
```

If to execute "make" from a bash it will respond:

```
$ make
Makefile:8: warning: overriding recipe for target 'target1'
Makefile:5: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'target1'
"target1 override"
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

This behavior is expected by me, because I expect that the latest definition of the target will be taken by Makefile's parser.

Is it legal to expect that the latest rule from the Makefile will be taken if the rule is overridden?

Is it possible to get rid of warnings?

P.S. Also I have tried answers from another StackOverflow's questions like the use of "override" keyword and "::" symbols. It doesn't help (errors and the same warnings from Makefile appears).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it legal to expect that the latest rule from the Makefile will be
>   taken if the rule is overridden?

A makefile that contains multiple target rules that provide recipes for the same target violates [the POSIX specifications for `make`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html):

> Only one target rule for any given target can contain commands.

Violating that will not bring the police down on you, but it may, rightfully, bring down the wrath of other developers and managers who have to work with your code, now or later.  Implementations of `make` are not bound by the spec to any particular behavior when a makefile containing such multiple recipes is presented.

The diagnostic messages you present and the behavior you describe appear characteristic of GNU `make`.  To the extent that you are willing to be dependent on that particular `make` implementation, it would be reasonable to rely on [section 4.11 of its manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Targets), which says:

> There can only be one recipe to be executed for a file. If more than
>   one rule gives a recipe for the same file, make uses the last one
>   given and prints an error message.<sup>*</sup>

(Footnote mine.) But reliance on that renders your makefile non-portable.  Other `make` implementations might instead reject the makefile, choose the first recipe, choose a random recipe, choose all matching recipes in some order, or exhibit any manner of obvious or non-obvious breakage.  Alerting you to that is the purpose of the message.

> Is it possible to get rid of warnings?

Continuing to assume GNU `make`, the manual says definitively that a diagnostic will be emitted, and [its summary of command-line options](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary) does not describe any that I would expect to suppress the output in question without also suppressing the actual build.

***Bottom line***

The question conveys the impression that you think the usage described ought to be acceptable, so that the diagnostic is merely a nuisance.  This is not the case.  Such usage is poor style, at least, and it can present genuine problems for yourself and others.  Whatever you're trying to accomplish that way, there are better alternatives.

---

<sup>*</sup>It's referring to *target* rules.  Suffix and pattern rules that match the target are a different matter.

Comment: I was not sure about the correctness of proposed implementation. Therefore, I decided to ask a question here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this perfect proof that proposed solution must be rejected at all.